# Site desconfigurado após alteração no .htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Eu desenvolvi um site, porém fui ao **.htaccess** do projeto para aplicar uma regra para forçar o **HTTPS** na página (Somente por caráter explorativo, eu não iria aplicar isso dessa forma.). Vejam abaixo a regra implementada:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
</IfModule>
```

Ocorre que, após fazer isso, o meu site redirecionou normalmente (estou usando o **Browser-sync** para *auto-refresh*), mas aí ele desconfigurou completamente. Se você inspecionar o código, ele está perfeito. No **DevTools** do navegador ele mostra nenhum erro (ou nenhum erro relevante ao problema em questão — vale ressaltar que, em alguns *refresh*, o console mostra alguns *warning*).

> Vocês podem ver o site aqui: brengenharia.com.br

**O que já tentei para resolver o problema:**

• Verificar erros no *DevTools* [Sem status];
• A regra do *.htaccess* já foi removido mas a desconfiguração permanece [Não resolveu];
• Aplicar a regra reversa (Forçar *HTTP*) [Não resolveu];
• Identificar tags abertas no *HTML* [Não resolveu];
• Tentar limpar cache ou acessar browser anônimo [Não resolveu];

Bom, é isso. Eu realmente preciso da ajuda de vocês. Digam-me se já tiveram situação semelhante, como resolveram ou como resolveriam, onde verificariam para tentar resolver.

Comment: Você tem certeza que está editando o arquivo no host certo?

Comment: Claro. Se eu já fiz o site inteiro lá. Mais alguma dica???????

Comment: Reiniciou o Apache?

Comment: Sim. Eu não gerencio o servidor mas já pedi que reiniciasse e o problema persiste.